# Success function in jQuery AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Yet another issue with my code.
I'm trying to attach a function in the event of a successful request, but it doesn't seem to be working.
My code so far:

```
const nbg = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://rmpc/json/notices.json",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      alert("WORKS");
    }
  });
};
```

Yet, whenever I try `success: alert("WORKS")` it suddenly works.
I'm incredibly confused by this.
Any ideas?
Thanks

> Edit: 'rmpc' is a local web server on my home network, might I add

Comment: Is the response from the file valid json?  An ajax request that has `dataType: 'json'` on it **must** return valid json, even if it is just `{}`.  jQuery will try to parse the response in this case and if it is not valid, or not set, it will error, regardless of if the response was a 200 or not.

Comment: I hope it helps
[Ajax success function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892706/ajax-success-function)

Comment: Check the browsers console. You have be facing a CORS problem.

Comment: `success: alert("WORKS")` will fire when page load since `()` will trigger it. try to paste `$.ajax({
    url: "http://rmpc/json/notices.json",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: alert("WORKS")
  });` in console

Comment: As far as I can tell. This is the file:

{
"notices":[
{
"name":"Raphael",
"notice":"teststetset",
"dati":"02/03/2018 23:27"
},
]}

Comment: I see a trailing comma. `"dati":"02/03/2018 23:27" },`  remove the comma

Comment: @Taplar That worked, thanks

Comment: K, since it was just a comma in a file, i'm going to flag as typo for close.

Comment: Well `success: alert("WORKS")` is calling alert and assigning what it returns to success.  SInce alert does not return anything, it is basically doing `success: undefined`

Comment: If you're getting a trailing comma in the JSON, it must mean that you're trying to create the JSON by hand, instead of using a library. **Don't do that**. You will invariably do it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It means that request is not success, so it must be an error. You need to catch it as well to find out:

```
const nbg = function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://rmpc/json/notices.json",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      alert("WORKS");
    },
    error: function (xhr, error) {
      console.debug(xhr); 
      console.debug(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I think you missed that I did try `success: alert("Works")`, which did work, so the request is a success. I know it has to be a syntax problem. (or something else)

Comment: `success: alert("WORKS")` will fire when page load since () will trigger it. try to paste `$.ajax({ url: "http://rmpc/json/notices.json", method: "GET", dataType: "json", cache: false, success: alert("WORKS") })` in chrome console - it will alert immediately;

Comment: could be the `trailing comma` in the JSON file that you send as well. see comment on your question above :)