# OctoberCMS callback for successful DB action after AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, octobercms

Im sending data via AJAX from my Chrome-extension to my OctoberCMS controller.
How can I recognize in my Chrome-extension that the database operation was successful?
So the goal is that I can use the `done()` in my AJAX call after a successful database update.
Do I have to return something from my controller?

**Ajax from extension**

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: "/saveData",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { "data": data}
}).done(function((){//does nothing});
```

**OctoberCMS Controller**

```
  function saveData(Request $request)
{
    $data = post('data');

    //do some actions with the data;
    
    DB::table('users')->where(['id' => Auth::getUser()->id])->update(['data' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: fix ur ajax syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892706/ajax-success-function/22892729

Comment: @KamleshPaul syntax is correct jQuery now using promise to handle stuff so its like that

Answer (score 2):

You can check for response

### From server side

```php
function saveData(Request $request)
{
    $data = post('data');

    //do some actions with the data;
    
    DB::table('users')->where(['id' => Auth::getUser()->id])->update(['data' => $data]);

    // if all good return success
    return ['success' => true];
    // if something is not correct
    // return ['success' => false];
}
```

### Client side

```js
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: "/saveData",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { "data": data}
}).done(function((data){
    if(data.success == true) {
       // yes all good data is updated
    }
    else {
       // data is not updated some error handling 
    }
}).fail(function() { 
    // data is not updated some error handling 
    // failed in case server is not able to answer or error 
});
```

if any doubt please comment.